# Lets Encrypt Configuration with traefik

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, lets-encrypt, toml

Good evening guys,

I having trouble with configuring a https connection for my trafik docker container.
Accessing http://example.com is working with the following configuration. But if I uncomment the last two lines of my `app` container, I get two different errors

http://example.com -> 404 page not found

https://example.com -> This site can't be reached. mydomain.com refused to connect.

See all information below. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

docker-compose.yml:

```
proxy:
   container_name: proxy
   image: traefik:v2.6
   ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:433"
     - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
     - "./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     - /etc/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt

# PHP/Apache container
app:
   container_name: php-node
   image: projectx/php-node
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./docker/php-node/Dockerfile
   restart: always
   labels:
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
  #   - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=websecure"
  #   - "traefik.http.routers.app.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
```

traefik.toml:

```
[log]
  level = "DEBUG"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
  email = "myname@mydomain.com"
  storage = "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlsChallenge]
```

Logs (with last two lines uncommented):

```
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) example.com"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="child http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:80 now UP"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Propagating new UP status"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery entryPointName=websecure middlewareType=Recovery
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure routerName=app@docker serviceName=app-examplecom middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" serviceName=app-examplecom entryPointName=websecure routerName=app@docker
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:80" routerName=app@docker serverName=0 serviceName=app-examplecom entryPointName=websecure
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="child http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:80 now UP"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Propagating new UP status"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware app-examplecom" middlewareName=tracing entryPointName=websecure routerName=app@docker middlewareType=TracingForwarder
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery entryPointName=websecure middlewareType=Recovery
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for example.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=websecure
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [example.com] found in HostSNI rule" routerName=app@docker rule="Host(`example.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"example.com\"]..." ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=app@docker rule="Host(`example.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme
time="2022-02-28T18:58:36Z" level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"example.com\"]." rule="Host(`example.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=app@docker
```

Comment: Are you exposing the port 80 on your php/apache container? Since traefik is taking care of the TLS connection, your php/apache container needs to accept incoming requests on port 80, not 443. Also, you might want to add the appropriate label for the loadbalancer server port.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My apache container cannot export port 80 because the port is already in use by the proxy container.

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I meant that you should add the label `traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=80` to your app service. But now that I look at the log I don't believe that will help since traefik does seem to know that apache is running on port 80.

Comment: Maybe add the label `traefik.http.routers.app.tls=true`? See this post [Traefik 2 & TLS 101](https://traefik.io/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/)